# Import Map Package (mpk) into ArcGIS Pro: How to create sources independent from the user's profile

Tags: arcgis-pro, data-source, map-package

After importing an ArcMap Map Package file (*.mpk) into ArcGIS Pro, the layers show Data Source starting with `C:\Users\<current user>\Documents\ArcGIS\Packages\`. This is useless for other users as they usually can not access this user-specific source. How does one have to handle Data Source of the layers in ArcGIS Pro in such a case so that other users can use this project in ArcGIS Pro as well?

Comment: the creator of the .mpk needs to use relative paths

Comment: Does this mean, that nothing can be done from the receiver's side in a case as described in the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One of the major features of packages is that they are ultimately useable without updating links to data.

If you want to save your packages to a more accessible location in ArcPro (or ArcMap), you can change the default location. Each user does this in their general options. So you could put packages on a share drive folder.
[See ArcPro package sharing.](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/sharing/overview/introduction-to-sharing-packages.htm)

Each user can decide where to unpack the map and data. The unpacking should re-create links so they work at the user's chosen location. In other words, unpacking uses relative paths.